# pytesseract on windows 10 : Error opening data file

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract on windows `10 x64`, and python is `3.5.2 x64`,Tesseract is `4.0`,the code is as follow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract


print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('d:/testimages/name.gif'), lang='chi_sim'))
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('d:/testimages/name.gif'), lang='chi_sim'))
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 165, in image_to_string
    raise TesseractError(status, errors)
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata')
```

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`,like this:

[image]

why is it?

Comment: Does it work for other languages?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672531/annoying-python-tesseract-error-error-opening-data-file-tessdata-eng-trainedda

Answer (score 0):

Set `TESSDATA_PREFIX` environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\`

Answer (score 0):

If you have tessdata error like: “Error opening data file…”

```
tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "<replace_with_your_tessdata_dir_path>"'
# Example config: '--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'
# It's important to add double quotes around the dir path.

pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='chi_sim', config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

Comment: tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "C:\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'